# Why am I getting "missing ';' before '*' "?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm new in c++ and I am working some stuff with cocos2d-x

I wanted to create just a simple Size property in the .h file to use in the implementation along different methods keeping its state.

what am I missing here?

```
#ifndef __INTROBETTER_SCENE_H__
#define __INTROBETTER_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"

class IntroBetterScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(IntroBetterScene);

private:
    void GoToMainMenuScene(float dt);
    Size* sizeWindow;

};

#endif //__INTROBETTER_SCENE_H__
```

Comment: Paste the entire error here; generally that error is the last in a long list of problems, and the real issue is higher up in the compiler output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you did not specify the correct scope. There is no class `Size` in the current scope. You need to use `cocos2d::Size`.